# Additional test configurations sbt, scala

Tags: scala, testing, playframework, sbt

I want to run test each test folders (models, API ...) separately with a different command.

example:

models:test (run test/models)

controllers:test (run test/controllers)

So my directory looks like this:

- app

  - models
  - controllers
  - helpers
- test

  - models
  - api
  - controllers
  - helpers

Is it possible?

Comment: Try to avoid simple yes/no questions.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I'm doing it in my project. No additional configuration needed if you put all you tests within the test directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define additional test configs and apply filters. e.g. to run tests for models only, in your project/Build.scala file create a  models configuration and filter tests to run based on file name endings.

```
lazy val ModelTest = config("models") extend(Test)

def modelFilter(name: String): Boolean = (name endsWith "ModelTest")

lazy val project = Project("project-name", file("."))
.settings(testOptions in ModelTest := Seq(Tests.Filter(modelFilter)))
```

More about testing in [SBT Reference](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html) and in [this blog post](https://orrsella.com/2014/09/24/integration-and-end-to-end-test-configurations-in-sbt-for-scala-java-projects/)